# In Matthew 12:10-13, why does Jesus equate a withered (ξηράν) hand (χεῖρα) as a pit (βόθυνον) to be saved from?

Tags: matthew, parables, parallelism

We read in Matthew 12:10-13, that Jesus equates having a withered (ξηράν) hand (χεῖρα) to being trapped in a pit (βόθυνον) :

Matthew 12:10-13 [KJV]

> [10] And, behold, there was a man which had his hand withered. And they asked him, saying, Is it lawful to heal on the sabbath days? that they might accuse him.
>
> [11] And he said unto them, What man shall there be among you, that shall have one sheep, and **if it fall into a pit on the sabbath day, will he not lay hold on it, and lift it out**?
>
> [12] How much then is a man better than a sheep? Wherefore it is lawful to do well on the sabbath days.
>
> [13] Then saith he to the man, **Stretch forth thine hand. And he stretched it forth; and it was restored whole**, like as the other.

Surely the man with the withered hand was not trapped from living a full life.  - **Why was Jesus' Pit parable necessary?**

Answer (score 1):

Jesus was NOT equating the withered hand with being trapped in a pit.  In using the pit story, Jesus is using a simple piece of Rabbinic reasoning, namely:

- If something is true for a simple case, it is true for the greater case.

Thus, Jesus' logic goes something like this:

- the simple case is an animal is found trapped on the Sabbath and so should be freed on the Sabbath
- Humans are greater and more important than animals
- Therefore, it is lawful to heal a person from their infirmity on the Sabbath.

Benson expresses the problem this way:

> Matthew 12:11-13. And he said — That he might show their
> unreasonableness, and confute them by their own practice: What man —
> that shall have —
>
> Or, Who, if he have but one sheep, that on the sabbath day shall fall
> into a pit, and it be in danger of perishing there, will not lay hold
> on it, &c. —
>
> The stress of the question does not lie on supposing a man to have
> only one sheep, but on one only falling into a pit; and yet, for the
> comparatively small value of that one, his not scrupling to undertake
> the labour of helping it out on the sabbath day. How much then is a
> man better than a sheep? As if he had said, If the regard you have for
> the life of your cattle leads you to do servile work on the sabbath,
> for the preservation of a single sheep, charity should much rather
> induce you to labour for the preservation of a fellow-creature, though
> the good office is to be done on the sabbath day. Wherefore it is
> lawful to do well — To save a beast, much more a man, or to perform
> any of the lovely acts of mercy and charity on the sabbath day.

The Pulpit commentary is even more pointed:

> Verse 11. - Matthew alone on this occasion, but comp. Luke 14:5. And
> he said unto them. Christ's answer appeals from intellectual and
> theoretical difficulties to the practical common sense of ordinary
> morality (cf. Romans 3:5-7). Their own feelings would guide them to
> help a brute, much more a man. According to the parallel passages, our
> Lord first set the man in the midst of them, wishing, perhaps, to draw
> out their sympathy, and only afterwards spoke this verse of censure
> (see Chrysostom). What man shall there be among you, that shall have
> one sheep. One only, and therefore so much the dearer (Meyer). He
> would feel an interest in it as an animal that he had learned to love;
> and he would care for it as his property. In Christ's case also there
> was the love of man as man, and of man as belonging to him (John
> 10:14; John 1:11). In Luke 14:5 ("a son or an ox") the double thought
> is distributed over two objects; the man Would love his son, and care
> for his property in the ox. And if it (this, Revised Version) fall
> into a pit on the sabbath day, will he not lay hold on it, and lift it
> out? Lightfoot ('Hor. Hebr.') confirms this from the Jerusalem Talmud
> and Maimonides.